# Tie Spring Liveness probe to custom HealthCheck

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-check, kubernetes-health-check

Having a SpringBoot application, where I try to tie my custom HealthCheck to the Spring Liveness probe. Although, it seems not to work. Please see my code below:

```kotlin
@Component
class CustomHealthIndicator() : HealthIndicator {


    override fun health(): Health {
        Thread.sleep(20000)
        return Health.down().build()
    }
}
```

In my `application.properties`, I've added my `CustomHealthIndicator` to the liveness group like this:

`management.endpoint.health.group.liveness.include=livenessState,custom`

Through this, I expect, that the `livenessState` of my SpringBoot application  will report it's status as `down`.
Although, it does not seem to work, the status is report as `up`.

What am I missing here?
I did follow the blog entry here: https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/25/liveness-and-readiness-probes-with-spring-boot and it should work like this, according to the author...

Thanks for any input!